# Validity of Anti-request forgery token in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, csrf

I have MVC application, during the pen test of the application, The Pen test team highlighted that `__RequestVerificationToken` value can be reused (i.e., they can issue POST request using a `__RequestVerificationToken` value which was generated for the previous request of the page or during the previous login session of the same user)

Is there any configuration where we can control the validity of the `__RequestVerificationToken` value being generated?

cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User", FormMethod.Post, role = "form", novalidate = "false"
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ///// some more code
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(parameter)
{
    //// some code 
}
```

Comment: There is no custom implementation. its just out of box feature from MVC.

Comment: add code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

XSRF tokens are **session based**, which means the existing token can and will be used multiple times within the same session.

Your first test case is not valid, the same cookie can be reused for the same user... but your second test case is valid, the user should not be able to reuse the same token after logging out. Make sure the session is cleared in your logout method.

More info about [XSRF token generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages#generating-the-tokens):

> If the current HTTP request already contains an anti-XSRF session
>   token (the anti-XSRF cookie __RequestVerificationToken), the security
>   token is extracted from it. If the HTTP request does not contain an
>   anti-XSRF session token or if extraction of the security token fails,
>   a new random anti-XSRF token will be generated.

Comment: Thanks, but it's strange that there is a need for calling Session.Adandon() explicitly. Let me try that out.

Comment: @jk.shan: are you using MS built-in Identity to logout, i.e. `AuthenticationManager.SignOut`? It would be good to share your logout Action method.